# Differential Equation $y’ =e^{x+y} +x^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals

So i was solving book Vinay kumar integral calculus for jee advanced and was stuck along with my friends for a long time on this question:
$$y' =e^{x+y} +x^2$$
I tried adding 1 on both sides and putting $x+y=t$ which gave the equation $d(t)/d(x)=e^t+x^2 +1$ but i am stuck on what to do after that .

Comment: Do not repost the same question. Wait for it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

$$y' =e^{x+y} +x^2$$
Multiply by $-e^{-y}$:
$$-e^{-y}y' +x^2e^{-y}=-e^{x} $$
$$(e^{-y})' +x^2e^{-y}=-e^{x} $$
$$t' +x^2t=-e^{x} $$
Where $t=e^{-y}$. Use  integrating factor method to solve.

Comment: Could you show me the steps after this , I am unable to solve after this step .

Comment: Multiply by $e^{x^3/3}$ then integrate  .....  leave the RHS as an integral if it's not possible to evalate the integral @VaasuKansal

Comment: Ok , thanks , i was thinking maybe $ e^((x^3)/3) $ was integrable .

Comment: I don't think it is so leave the integral on RHS as it is @VaasuKansal